# App crashing reason: '-[HOV1.itemShowViewController collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcc8f6a1320'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

```
** it just crashes whenever I click the table to load the new view 
controller  reason: '-[HOV1.itemShowViewController collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:]:
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcc8f6a1320'**
```

idk if its an identifier or just the code im not too sure it should be working I swear it had worked last night but today it just keeps crashing ive tried restarting Xcode rebuilding the app

```
import UIKit

 class ItemsTableViewController: UITableViewController {


var category : Category?

var itemArray : [Item] = []


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("we have selected" , category?.name )


    self.title = category?.name

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if category != nil {

        LoadItems()
    }
}



    // MARK: - Table view data source

     /* override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 0
     }*/

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int         {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return itemArray.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->    UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "addItemCell", for: indexPath)
        as! ITEMTableViewCell  //you need to specify which cell it needs to be talking too    so this one talks to item table view cell

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.generateCellForITEMS(item: itemArray[indexPath.row])

    return cell
}


//MARK: TABLEVIEW DELEGATE

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    //so when this the tables are tapped they will open up  a new view controller

    showItemsView(itemArray[indexPath.row]) //selects the item i want and passes it to the show item function
}




// MARK: - Navigation

//In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

   //gives u access to category function in add item viewcontroller
    if segue.identifier == "AddItemSegue" {

        let vc = segue.destination as! AddItemViewController
        vc.category = category!
    }
}





private func showItemsView(_ _item : Item){

    //reason i have a if available code is because it gave me a problem about the version so using this code im able to check the version and use the approprate function the difference is the identfier one says "identifier" the other one says with "withidentifier"

    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        let itemVC = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "itemVieww") as! itemShowViewController

         itemVC.item  = _item

         self.navigationController?.pushViewController(itemVC, animated: true)
    }

    else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        let itemVC = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "itemVieww") as! itemShowViewController

        itemVC.item  = _item

         self.navigationController?.pushViewController(itemVC, animated: true)
    }
}







   private func LoadItems(){

  let item = Item()
item.downloadITEMSFromFirebase(withCategoryId: category!.id) { (allItems) in

    print("we have \(allItems.count) items for this category")
    self.itemArray = allItems
    self.tableView.reloadData()
  }
 }





}
```

idk if its an identifier or just the code im not too sure it should be working I swear it had worked last night but today it just keeps crashing ive tried restarting Xcode rebuilding the app

code for itemshowViewcontroller

```
import UIKit
import JGProgressHUD

 class itemShowViewController: UIViewController {


//MARK: VARS
var item : Item!
var itemImages : [UIImage] = []

let hud2 = JGProgressHUD(style: .dark)


//MARK: VIEW LIFECYCLE
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

   // print("Item Name is", item.name)
   }


//MARK: IBOUTLETS
@IBOutlet weak var imageCollectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var priceLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var descriptionTextView: UITextView!




}
```

Comment: add code of `itemShowViewController`

Comment: just added code for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't implement `numberOfItemsInSection` && `cellForItemAt` inside `itemShowViewController` as you set the delegate and dataSource inside the storyborad/xib